# Linearly independent coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, coordinate-systems

Consider the coordinate transformation $$(x,y)\to (a(x,y),b(x,y)).$$

I'm told that in order for $a(x,y)$ and $b(x,y)$ to be linearly independent, we must have $$\begin{vmatrix} \frac{\partial a}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial a}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial b}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial b}{\partial y}\end{vmatrix} \neq 0.$$

I'm not sure how to justify why this condition ensures linear independence.

For a set of vectors $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$, I know that these are linearly independent if \begin{align*} \lambda_1v_1+\cdots+\lambda_nv_n=0 \implies \lambda_1=\cdots =\lambda_n=0.\end{align*}

I'm unsure of how to apply this idea to get the condition above though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The condition is about [Jacobian determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Jacobian_determinant) and assures that the transformation is locally invertible, thus the gradient vectors of $a$ and $b$ must be linearly independent.